Option to modify SAML20AssertionValidators.attributeValidator in OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider
SAML20AssertionValidators.attributeValidator is hardcoded in OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.java  with default conditions:

AudienceRestrictionConditionValidator
DelegationRestrictionConditionValidator
ConditionValidator
ProxyRestrictionConditionValidator

And a subject:

BearerSubjectConfirmationValidator

Is there any option available to modify only the subject and retain all the default conditions?

Note: createDefaultAssertionValidatorWithParameters() or createDefaultAssertionValidator() does not seem to support the modification of attributeValidator.

